# Weird Acitivity Memory Leak Android 8.1

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

Iam getting a weird memory leak in my activity. Iam using the latest Leak Canary.
I dont think that is an actual leak, because i have tested in api 21 and api 27 and i dont get this message. Though apis 21,27 were tested on emulator only and the 8.1 was on an actual device, maybe thats the difference.

I dont have those classes anywhere in my code.

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.1'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.1'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using **proguard**? it's possible because of obfuscation, that original classes got renamed !

Comment: @JeelVankhede You mean this? proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'. Then yes.

Comment: If you're using `minify.enabled = true` which means proguard applies and uses obfuscation, it should be reason why you're getting such kind of class names, if you try disabling minify, you can see your classnames as definded in source code.

Comment: I am facing the same and I am confused if Crashlytics can mange while using proguard, isn't it possible for LeakCanary too? Some might really want to run a debug build keeping proguard on ...